# How to use Favicon in Maven based Java web application?

Tags: java, maven, jsp, favicon

I have a web application developed in `Java`, and it is in `Maven` structure. I added the `favicon.png` to `src/main/resources` location and used the following tagline in JSP.

```
<head>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
</head>
```

But unfortunately the favicon is not visible. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The favicon should be in your context root.

If you have `src\main\webapp` place it there, also if you want to load from classpath place it in `src\main\resources\META-INF\resources`

*NOTE:* If your application have context other than root (i.e. `\`) then you have to append it to the href.